# How to validate kendo date time picker

Tags: kendo-ui

I am working on Kendo date time picker.I am getting a problem when clicking the submit button.
        1)Having To date and From date pickers .how to get the popup that should validate both the date and time and it should not allows the alphabets.

```
 $("#startdatetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
 showSecond: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
      timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
      format: "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss",

      mindate: getFormattedDate(new Date())

  }).data("kendoDateTimePicker");

$("#startdatetimepic").attr("readonly", "readonly");
function getFormattedDate(date) {
       alert("")
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = date.getFullYear().toString().slice(2);
    return day + '-' + month + '-' + year;


}
 $("#enddatetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({

      showSecond: true,
      dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
      timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
      format: "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss"
  }).data("kendoDateTimePicker");


  var result = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      filterable: true,


      columns: [{
          field: "FirstName",
          title: "First Name"
      }, {
          field: "LastName",
          title: "Last Name"
      }, {
          field: "dob",
          title: "DOB",
          format: "{0:dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss}"
      }],
      dataSource: {
          data: [ {
              FirstName: "Joe",
              LastName: "Smith",
              dob: "2013-02-01 19:54:13"
          }, {
              FirstName: "Jane",
              LastName: "Smith",
              dob: "2013-02-02 20:55:14"
          }, {
              FirstName: "Jane",
              LastName: "Smith",
              dob: "2013-02-03 21:56:15"
          },
         {
              FirstName: "Jane",
              LastName: "Smith",
              dob: "2013-03-4 20:56:14"
          }],
          schema: {


              data: function (data) {
                  $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                      val.dob = kendo.parseDate(val.dob, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                  });
                  return data;
              }
          }

      }
  }).data("kendoGrid");


  $("#filter").on("click", function () {
      var mindate = $('#startdatetimepicker').data("kendoDateTimePicker").value();
      var maxdate = $('#enddatetimepicker').data("kendoDateTimePicker").value();

      var condition = {
          logic: "and",
          filters: []
      };
      if (mindate !== null) {
          condition.filters.push({
              field: "dob",
              operator: "ge",
              value: mindate
          });
      }
      if (maxdate !== null) {
          condition.filters.push({
              field: "dob",
              operator: "le",
              value: maxdate
          });
      }
      result.dataSource.filter(condition);


  });
here is the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/5bchz/97/
```

Comment: hi  help me anyone i am also having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The format should prohibit alpha characters while incrementing the values can be achieved similar to:

```
function incrementDay(increment) {
            var datePicker = $("#DayPager").data("kendoDatePicker");
            var val = datePicker.value();
            var newDate = new Date(val.getFullYear(), val.getMonth(), val.getDate() + increment);           
            datePicker.value(newDate);           
        }
```